# What is ApplyBuiltinRootMotion and how to use it?

Tags: unity, animation, animator, character-controller, root-motion

The character in my game has humanoid feature. I have unchecked "Apply Root Motion" in Animator component and use scripts for its movements. I want to implement a Ledge Grab Jumping movement. 
How can I use "ApplyBuiltinRootMotion" function in this case? 
What do I need to know about this function and to make it work really ?

```
 private void OnAnimatorMove()
 {
       _animator.ApplyBuiltinRootMotion();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a script on your gameObject that implements `OnAnimatorMove()`, then the root motions of any animations are ignored. That is unfortunately not documented in OnAnimatorMove where you would expect it, but in the documentation of the [Animator.applyRootMotion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-applyRootMotion.html) property:

> Root motion is the effect where an object's entire mesh moves away from its starting point but that motion is created by the animation itself rather than by changing the Transform position. Note that applyRootMotion has no effect when the script implements a MonoBehaviour.OnAnimatorMove function.

However, sometimes you have the case that you want to use your own root motion logic only in *some* cases while you have other cases where you want to leave the root motion to the animation clip. In that case, you call `animator.ApplyBuiltinRootMotion()` within OnAnimatorMove to restore the normal behavior. The code in the question is of course rather pointless. It takes over control of root motion by having an implementation of OnAnimatorMove, but then it hands root motion control right back to the animation system by calling `ApplyBuiltinRootMotion()`.But you might have code like this where this method is only executed when you are not in a state where you have an own root motion implementation:

```
 private void OnAnimatorMove()
 {
     if (ourAnimationUsesCustomRootMotion == true) {
        // We are currently handling root motion manually
        transform.position += ourRootMotionVector;
     } else {
        // We don't have custom root motion enabled right now, so let's leave it to the animation system
        _animator.ApplyBuiltinRootMotion();
     }
 }
```